# How to configure Python in XCode 4.6?

Tags: python, xcode, configuration, installation

I really tried looking for a solution and couldn't find a simple method to do it.

How can I configure **XCode 4.6** for **Python 2.7** so that I can code and run the simulation through it ?

Answer (score 0):

https://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/building-and-running-python-scripts-with-xcode-4-x/

I had a bit of trouble getting the custom working directory option to actually work, though..